# When I put to Drive my transmission goes to manual

Tags: automatic-transmission, kia, rio

KIA RIO 2013 model. I have the option to put it to "D" or +/- for manual. After starting the vehicle I shift from "P" to "D" and it won't move. When I step on the accelerator it goes to "1" even though the transmission is on "D" which forces me to go to +/-. Even though I go back to "D" after a few meters it will still remain in Manual mode. Please help.

I think the problem is the sensor on the "D" of the transmission lever itself. If that's the case, is it easy to replace? I can't find a video in YouTube on 'How to'.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure exactly what's going on here. You realize the vehicle starts off in "1" or first gear even when you put the vehicle in "D"? Obviously there's something going on, which could be either the shifter or the transmission. If you are the original owner of the vehicle, how many miles are on the vehicle? Your vehicle may be still under warranty for powertrain (including the transmission) problems, even in Saudi Arabia.

Comment: The vehicle is 85K KM (4 1/2 yrs.). I'm not the original user, just got it from a friend who went for exit and still under mortgage. I'll check on the warranty.

I think the problem is with the sensor because when I move around the shifter it sometimes shows "D".